# Data not rendering in lightning-data-table in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using LWD lightning data table to display list of accounts from apex controller using imperative apex method call. I see that data is getting set in `property {accounts}` and even in UI when i check {account.Name} its displaying in UI but the data is not rendering in `lightning-data-table`

> I am getting an empty table even with No columns.

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
            Search Account with Account Name here.
        </h2>
        <div if:true={isLoaded} class="slds-is-relative">
            <lightning-spinner variant="brand" size="large"> </lightning-spinner>
        </div>
        <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow">
            <lightning-input type="search" label="Account Name" name="Account Name"
                placeholder="Search Account Name."  class="slds-size_2-of-2 slds-m-left_x-small"
                onchange={handleKeyChange}></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Search" title="Search" onclick={searchAccounts}
            class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
    </div>
    <template lwc:if={accounts}>
        <div style="height: 300px;">
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={accounts}
                    columns={columns}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
        </template>
     <!--<c-display-Accounts-In-Table accounts={accounts}></c-display-Accounts-In-Table>-->
     <template lwc:if={accounts}>
        <template for:each={accounts} for:item="account">
            <p key={account.Id}>{account.Name}</p>
        </template>
    </template>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import getAccountsData from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.findAccounts';

const columns = [
    { label: 'AccountNumber', fieldName: 'AccountNumber',type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'BillingCity', fieldName: 'BillingCity', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone' }
];
export default class FetchAccountDetails extends LightningElement {
    isLoaded;
    eneteredAccountName;
    @track accounts;
    error;

    handleKeyChange(event) {
        //alert(event.target.value)
        this.eneteredAccountName = event.target.value;
    }
    searchAccounts() {
        
        this.isLoaded = true;
        getAccountsData({searchKey: this.eneteredAccountName}).then(result => {
            this.accounts = result;
            this.isLoaded = false;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error)
            this.error = error;
            this.isLoaded = false;
          });
    }
   


    
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class AccountController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> findAccounts(String searchKey) {
        system.debug('searchKey--->>>>'+searchKey);
        String key = '%' + searchKey + '%';
        return [
            SELECT AccountNumber, Name, BillingCity,Phone
            FROM Account
            WHERE Name LIKE :key
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could only refer class properties in the template, see [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/js-props-getter.html):

> Bind properties in a component’s template to **properties in the component’s JavaScript class**.

`columns` is a static constant defined only outside of the class, so the datatable cannot access it, that's the issue.

In order to expose it you could use a getter:

```js
const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'AccountNumber', fieldName: 'AccountNumber',type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'BillingCity', fieldName: 'BillingCity', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone' }
];

export default class FetchAccountDetails extends LightningElement {
    isLoaded;
    eneteredAccountName;
    accounts;
    error;
    
    get columns() {
        return COLUMNS;
    }
    
    // rest of the code
```

I changed the constant to `COLUMNS`. Keep in mind that Javascript is case-sensitive.

By the way, you don't need `@track` here. Properties used in the template are already reactive.

Comment: Thanks very much Ruben!! It worked..

Comment: One more thing i can also declare the values of columns inside the class right? what would be the diff?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal yes, of course the columns definition could be just inside the class, i.e. you could define the array in the getter, having something like `return [ { label: 'AccountNumber', fieldName: 'AccountNumber' }, /* and so on */ ];`. Everythng inside the class is an *instance* property, so different instances could have their own values for the same instance property. What lies outside the class is *static*, therefore shared between instances. Keep in mind that the code should be its own documentation, so if something should be a read-only property, define it using a getter.